# Command Line Countdown Timer Skipping a Second

Tags: powershell

I've been looking to add a simple countdown timer to my script. I found [this](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/start-countdowntimer/1.0/Content/Start-CountdownTimer.psm1) one that seemed to do the trick and modified it slightly to only display seconds since I don't need anything more than that.

When I run it, it will skip the 2nd second in the countdown. For example, if I ran `Start-CountdownTimer -Seconds 10`, the output will be (this is split into separate lines for demo purposes since it'll be on the same line):

```
 |  Starting in 10s ...
 /  Starting in 8s ...
 -  Starting in 7s ...
 \  Starting in 6s ...
 |  Starting in 5s ...
 /  Starting in 4s ...
 -  Starting in 3s ...
 \  Starting in 2s ...
 |  Starting in 1s ...
 /  Starting in 0s ...
```

Any ideas how I can fix this? This is the (slightly modified) code from the link above:

```
Function Start-CountdownTimer{
param (
    <#[int]$Days = 0,
    [int]$Hours = 0,
    [int]$Minutes = 0,#>
    [int]$Seconds = 0,
    [int]$TickLength = 1
)
$t = New-TimeSpan <#-Days $Days -Hours $Hours -Minutes $Minutes#> -Seconds $Seconds
$origpos = $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition
$spinner =@('|', '/', '-', '\')
$spinnerPos = 0
$remain = $t
$d =( get-date) + $t
$remain = ($d - (get-date))
while ($remain.TotalSeconds -gt 0){
  Write-Host (" {0} " -f $spinner[$spinnerPos%4]) -ForegroundColor White -NoNewline
  write-Host (" Starting in {0:d1}s ..." -f $remain.Seconds)
  $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $origpos
  $spinnerPos += 1
  Start-Sleep -seconds $TickLength
  $remain = ($d - (get-date))
}
$host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $origpos
}
```

Comment: All those `Write-Host` and `Get-Date` commands inside the loop use up processing time, so it should be no surprise if now and again this will 'skip' a second..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If you want a solution that *never skips a countdown step* - at the expense of running a bit *longer* than the specified countdown duration (increasingly so, the longer the duration) - see [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69770693/45375).
- If you want a solution that *may* skip a countdown step, under heavy system load, but *remains close to the specified countdown duration*, irrespective of its length, see below.

---

As [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) points out, your implementation is somewhat inefficient, which increases the risk of skipping a step.

The following is a **streamlined implementation** that *lessens* the risk of skipping, though under heavy system load it may still occur.

Note:

- The function does *not* work properly in the Windows PowerShell *ISE*, but the [ISE is *obsolescent*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and there have always been [reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section); by contrast, the function *does* work in the ISE's successor, [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)
- Instead of using `$host.UI.RawUI`, a simple CR (`` "`r" ``) is issued at the start of each countdown step's `Write-Host -NoNewLine` call, which causes the cursor to return to the start of the line and overwrite the existing line.
- To avoid flickering when the line is overwritten, the cursor is temporarily turned off, using `[Console]::CursorVisible]`
- Strictly speaking, based on PowerShell's description of its [approved verbs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands), your function should be named `Invoke-CoutdownTimer`, given that it executes *synchronously*, though the standard [`Start-Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep) is similarly misnamed - see [GitHub docs issue #4474](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/4474) for a discussion.

```
Function Start-CountdownTimer {
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateRange(0,999)]
    [int] $Seconds,
    [int] $SleepIntervalMilliSeconds = 1000
  )
  $spinner = '|', '/', '-', '\'
  $spinnerPos = 0
  [Console]::CursorVisible = $false
  $dtEnd = [datetime]::UtcNow.AddSeconds($Seconds)
  try {
    while (($remainingSecs = ($dtEnd - [datetime]::UtcNow).TotalSeconds) -gt 0) {
      Write-Host -NoNewline ("`r {0} " -f $spinner[$spinnerPos++ % 4]) -ForegroundColor White 
      Write-Host -NoNewLine (" Starting in {0,3}s ...  " -f [Math]::Ceiling($remainingSecs))
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds ([Math]::Min($SleepIntervalMilliSeconds, $remainingSecs * 1000))
    }
    Write-Host
  } 
  finally {
    [Console]::CursorVisible = $true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this should be an improvement to your `function` and also should solve the problem of jumping an extra second back. I personally do not agree with using `$host` and would use `Clear-Host` instead so the function is compatible with PowerShell ISE too but you can change that as you please.

```
Function Start-CountdownTimer{
param(
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Time')]
    [parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Hours')]
    [ValidateRange(1, [int]::MaxValue)]
    [int]$Hours = 0,
    [parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Minutes')]
    [ValidateRange(1, [int]::MaxValue)]
    [int]$Minutes = 0,
    [parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Seconds', Position = 0)]
    [ValidateRange(1, [int]::MaxValue)]
    [int]$Seconds = 0
)

    $now = [datetime]::Now
    $spinner = @('|', '/', '-', '\')
    $spinnerPos = 0
    $origpos = $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition

    $runTime = switch($PSBoundParameters.Keys)
    {
        Hours   { $now.AddHours($PSBoundParameters[$PSBoundParameters.Keys]) }
        Minutes { $now.AddMinutes($PSBoundParameters[$PSBoundParameters.Keys]) }
        Seconds { $now.AddSeconds($PSBoundParameters[$PSBoundParameters.Keys]) }
    }

    $runTime = $runTime.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds - $now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds

    while($runTime)
    {
        Write-Host (" {0} " -f $spinner[$spinnerPos%4]) -NoNewline
        Write-Host " Starting in ${runTime}s ..."
        $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $origpos
        $spinnerPos += 1
        $runTime--

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}
```